# Spark sql count hotel visits per month

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I need to count number of visits in hotel per month.
If visitor left not in the same month as he moved in, this should be counted as visit in every month he stayed in the hotel

`John` lived in hotel `A` in two months, so hotel had 1 visit in `09` month and 1 in `10` month
`Mark` stayed in hotel `A` only in one month, so +1 visit in `09` month
Total: month `09` - 2 visits, month `10` - 1 visit

I started writing query, but it becomes really huge with cte's (visits in same month, in different), unions and removing duplicates, and I feel like there should be a more elegant solution

So. is there a simple way do this?

| Hotel | Visitor | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | John | 22.09.2020 | 01.10.2020 |
| A | Mark | 22.09.2020 | 29.09.2020 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an approach to create a table for exhaustive list of months using your data and then map the data with it.

Sample data I used,

```py
# create data table
data_ls = [
    ('A', 'blah1', '2020-02-02', '2020-04-16'),
    ('A', 'blah2', '2020-02-02', '2020-03-01'),
    ('A', 'blah3', '2020-12-02', '2021-03-01'),
    ('A', 'blah4', '2020-12-02', '2021-03-01'),
    ('B', 'blah2', '2021-02-02', '2021-03-01')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['hotel', 'person', 'in', 'out']). \
    withColumn('in', func.col('in').cast('date')). \
    withColumn('out', func.col('out').cast('date'))

# +-----+------+----------+----------+
# |hotel|person|        in|       out|
# +-----+------+----------+----------+
# |    A| blah1|2020-02-02|2020-04-16|
# |    A| blah2|2020-02-02|2020-03-01|
# |    A| blah3|2020-12-02|2021-03-01|
# |    A| blah4|2020-12-02|2021-03-01|
# |    B| blah2|2021-02-02|2021-03-01|
# +-----+------+----------+----------+
```

The query below maps all the people within the manually created months table. The month table is created based on the years available in your hotel data and an exhaustive list of months.

```py
data_sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('hotel_data')

spark.sql('''
    select y.hotel, x.yyyymm, count(distinct y.person) as num_visits from (
        select a.mth, b.yr, concat(b.yr, a.mth) as yyyymm from (
        select '01' as mth union all 
        select '02' as mth union all 
        select '03' as mth union all 
        select '04' as mth union all 
        select '05' as mth union all 
        select '06' as mth union all 
        select '07' as mth union all 
        select '08' as mth union all 
        select '09' as mth union all 
        select '10' as mth union all 
        select '11' as mth union all 
        select '12' as mth) a
        cross join (
            select distinct year(in) as yr from hotel_data
            union
            select distinct year(out) as yr from hotel_data) b
        on 1=1) x
    left join hotel_data y
    on x.yyyymm >= date_format(y.in, 'yyyyMM')
    and x.yyyymm <= date_format(y.out, 'yyyyMM')
    where y.hotel is not null
    group by 1, 2
    order by 1, 2
''').show()

# +-----+------+----------+
# |hotel|yyyymm|num_visits|
# +-----+------+----------+
# |    A|202002|         2|
# |    A|202003|         2|
# |    A|202004|         1|
# |    A|202012|         2|
# |    A|202101|         2|
# |    A|202102|         2|
# |    A|202103|         2|
# |    B|202102|         1|
# |    B|202103|         1|
# +-----+------+----------+
```

- The first part (`x`) is to create an exhaustive list of months (`yyyyMM`). Bases on the data I used,

| mth | yr | yyyymm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020 | 202001 |
| 02 | 2020 | 202002 |
| 03 | 2020 | 202003 |
| 04 | 2020 | 202004 |
| 05 | 2020 | 202005 |
| 06 | 2020 | 202006 |
| 07 | 2020 | 202007 |
| 08 | 2020 | 202008 |
| 09 | 2020 | 202009 |
| 10 | 2020 | 202010 |
| 11 | 2020 | 202011 |
| 12 | 2020 | 202012 |
| 01 | 2021 | 202101 |
| 02 | 2021 | 202102 |
| 03 | 2021 | 202103 |
| 04 | 2021 | 202104 |
| ... | ... | ... |

- The next part joins the hotel data with the aforementioned such that the person is mapped with the months within the `in` and `out` dates. I create months (yyyyMM format) using `in` and `out` and check the condition if a month, from the exhaustive month table, is available between the `in` and `out` of a person.
- once joined, the query counts the unique number of people per hotel per month (from exhaustive month table).

Answer (score 1):

Try this spark-sql solution. I added one more row for a scenario covering in/out spanning diff years.

I used a reference month '2000-01-01', and you can change it to some old date to suit your requirements.

```
val mdf = spark.sql("""
select  'A' hotel, 'John' visitor ,to_date('2020-09-22') in, to_date('2020-10-01') out  union all
select  'A', 'Mark', '2020-09-22', '2020-09-29' union all
select  'A', 'Mark', '2019-09-22', '2020-09-29' 
""")
mdf.show(false)

+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|hotel|visitor|in        |out       |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|A    |John   |2020-09-22|2020-10-01|
|A    |Mark   |2020-09-22|2020-09-29|
|A    |Mark   |2019-09-22|2020-09-29|
+-----+-------+----------+----------+

mdf.createOrReplaceTempView("mdf")

spark.sql("""
select hotel, visitor, 
   int(months_between(out,'2000-01-01'))-int(months_between(in,'2000-01-01'))+1 as no_visits
  from mdf
""").show(false)

+-----+-------+---------+
|hotel|visitor|no_visits|
+-----+-------+---------+
|A    |John   |2        |
|A    |Mark   |1        |
|A    |Mark   |13       |
+-----+-------+---------+
```

Another solution using udf():

Below is the udf - we just the loop from start day to end day by converting them to Epoch days.

```
def months_between_t(start:java.sql.Date, end:java.sql.Date):Int={
      val st = start.toLocalDate
      val ed = end.toLocalDate
      val days_mm = for( i <- st.toEpochDay.toInt to ed.toEpochDay.toInt )
                 yield java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(i).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")).toString
      val months_mm = days_mm.distinct.length
    months_mm
}
```

Register the udf

```
val udf_months_between = udf ( months_between_t(_:java.sql.Date, _:java.sql.Date):Int)
```

Now call the udf

```
mdf.withColumn("num_of_visits",udf_months_between(col("in"),col("out"))).show(false)

+-----+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
|hotel|visitor|in        |out       |num_of_visits|
+-----+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
|A    |John   |2020-09-22|2020-10-01|2            |
|A    |Mark   |2020-09-22|2020-09-29|1            |
|A    |Mark   |2019-09-22|2020-09-29|13           |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with something like this?

```
select
  mnt.m,
  count(*)
from
  (
    select '01' as m union all
    select '02' as m union all
    select '03' as m union all
    select '04' as m union all
    select '05' as m union all
    select '06' as m union all
    select '07' as m union all
    select '08' as m union all
    select '09' as m union all
    select '10' as m union all
    select '11' as m union all
    select '12' as m
  ) as mnt      join
  left join your_data y
    on month(y.in) >= mnt.m
   and mnt.m <= month(y.in) + months_between(y.out,y.in)
group by mnt.m
```

I would take care of the year on this kind of queries.

Comment: what happens if the `in` is in December and `out` in February of the following year? I'm unable to understand how this'd work in such a case. I feel like this won't work. Better to use dates (start date of a month as `in` and end date of a month as `out`).

Comment: It won't work, as I said: "I would take care of the year on this kind of queries." If you are afraid about this, you should point it in your question (at least in your sample data...)

Comment: I'm not the OP. However, it looks like your answer won't be useful on an actual data, given the assumptions. I'd encourage you to add your assumptions to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a list of months.  You might have a calendar table.  Alternatively, if you have someone checking in every month, you can use that:

```
select yyyymm, count(*)
from (select distinct date_trunc(in, 'mm') as yyyymm
      from t
     ) ym join
     t
     on date_trunc(in, 'mm') <= yyyymm and
        date_trunc(out, 'mm') >= yyyymm
group by yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it using sql, you could do it this way:

```
with your_data as (
  select 'John' as Visitor, '2020-09-22' as [In], '2020-10-01' as [out] union all
  select 'Mark' as Visitor, '2020-09-22' as [In], '2020-09-29' as [out]
)
select 
  my.y as [Year], 
  mnt.m as [Month], 
  count(distinct concat(Visitor,y,m)) as Visitors
from
  (
    select 'mny' as t, min(year([in])) as y
    from your_data yydd
    union all
    select 'mny' as t,  max(year([out])) as y
    from your_data yydd 
   ) as my
  cross join
  (
    select '01' as m union all
    select '02' as m union all
    select '03' as m union all
    select '04' as m union all
    select '05' as m union all
    select '06' as m union all
    select '07' as m union all
    select '08' as m union all
    select '09' as m union all
    select '10' as m union all
    select '11' as m union all
    select '12' as m
  ) as mnt
  left join your_data y
    on
      (
        year(y.[in]) = my.y and 
        mnt.m between month(y.[in]) and case when month(y.[out]) < month(y.[in]) then '12' else month(y.[out]) end
      )
      or
      (
        year(y.[out]) = my.y and
        mnt.m between case when month(y.[out]) < month(y.[in]) then '01' else '13' end and month(y.[out])
      )
where Visitor is not null
group by my.y, mnt.m
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b9b7a91cabf3177ec5588311ab8bd72)

[image: IntraYear]

If you want to check the "interyear" behavior, replace by new dates:

```
with your_data as (
  select 'John' as Visitor, '2020-09-22' as [In], '2020-10-01' as [out] union all
  select 'Mark' as Visitor, '2020-09-22' as [In], '2021-04-29' as [out]
)
```

You can try in this [<>db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=defcff9ee81cb18af8bd2680cf34998f)

[image: inter year]

Comment: If you have Visitors standing for more than 2 consecutive years, you would have to artificially create the years between, otherwise it won't work as expected.